# Change form.item label font size in AntD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, styled-components, typography

I'm using styled components something like this

```
const FormItem = styled(Form.Item)`
     font-size: 16px;
`;
```

Using Form Item something like this

```
    <FormItem label="System Pressurized">
    {getFieldDecorator('systemPressurized')(
      <Select defaultValue="" placeholder="Select Type">
        <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
      </Select>,
    )}
  </FormItem>
```

I've tried changing font size of AntD but it doesn't seem to workout

Comment: you want to change formItem label or option label???

Comment: I want to change formItem label

Answer (score 12):

There are multiple options to override style elements.

1. You can directly override label elements from global CSS files like:

```
label { 
   font-size:16px;
}
```

2. Individual element by adding a script to the label element:

```
<FormItem 
  label={ <p style={{fontSize:"16px"}}>"System Pressurized"</p> }>
  { getFieldDecorator('systemPressurized')(
    <Select defaultValue="" placeholder="Select Type">
      <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
    </Select>
   )}
</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please override CSS in your code like

```
$ .ant-form-item-label>label {
     font-size: 16px;
 }
```

1. You can directly override the CSS in global.less file like

   ```
    & .ant-form-item-label {
       & > label {
        font-size: 16px;
       }
    }
   ```
2. You can write JSX for this

   ```
   <FormItem label = {
    <p style={{fontSize: "16px"}}>System Pressurized</p>}>
   {getFieldDecorator('systemPressurized')(
     <Select defaultValue="" placeholder="Select Type">
       <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
     </Select>,
   )}
   ```

Answer (score 1):

add css:

```css
.ant-form-item-label label{
   font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two way to style the formItem label

```
//way one :
//You can override the default css by override below selectors
.form-section .form-group label{
  font-size : 20px
  //YOUR CUSTOM STYLE
}
```

```
// way two : 
// You can pass custom component like below : 
  <FormItem label={<p style={YOURCUSTOMSTYLEOBJECT}>System Pressurized</p>}>
    {getFieldDecorator('systemPressurized')(
      <Select defaultValue="" placeholder="Select Type">
        <Option value="Yiminghe">yiminghe</Option>
      </Select>,
    )}
  </FormItem>
```

Comment: HI Afaq Ahmed Khan did you get it?

Comment: hey @sathish I couldn't figure out how this would work

Answer (score 0):

```
then use it like this


<!-- language: lang-js -->

    const formItemLayout =
      formLayout === 'horizontal' ?
      {
        labelCol: {
          span: 4,
          style: {
            "text-align": "left",
            "font-size": "12px"
          }
        },
        wrapperCol: {
          span: 30,
        },
      } :
      null;

<!-- end snippet -->
```

```html
//then use it like this
<Form
  {...formItemLayout}
  layout={formLayout}
  form={form}
  initialValues={{
      layout: formLayout,
  }}
>
  <Form.Item
    label={"Full Name"}
    name="username"
    id="name"
    style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}
    defaultValue={name}
    onChange={handleChange()}
    rules={[
        {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your name!',
        },
    ]}
    >
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```